# Need new line in SSRS matrix

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-tablix, ssrs-grouping, ssrs-2008-r2

I have the data int this format in our database -

```
Item1                            Item2
Processor   Intel i7-4558U  3.30GHz Intel i7-4500U  1.80GHz Intel i5-4200U  1.60GHz
Processor   Intel Atom™ N2600  1.60GHz
Processor   Intel i7-2670QM   Intel i5-2410M   Intel i3-2330M   Intel B950/B940
```

and in SSRS matrix report , I want to change the data in this format -

```
Processor Intel i7-4558U  3.30GHz
          Intel i7-4500U  1.80GHz
          Intel i5-4200U  1.60GHz
Processor Intel Atom™ N2600  1.60GHz
Processor Intel i7-2670QM   
          Intel i5-2410M 
          Intel i3-2330M  
          Intel B950/B940
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Showing in it matrix is easy. The task you have to do is splitting the values from the column item2. You have to write your sql in that way.

Comment: Thanks Aditya, Yeah If I am not able to achieve this in SSRS then I will handle this in SQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to update your SQL. Just replace the spaces before Intel with a `vbcrlf`:

```
=replace(Fields!Item2.Value," Intel",vbcrlf & "Intel")
```

[image]

Let me know if this helps or if I can help you further.

Comment: Thank you so much for your effort, I will check and let you know.

Comment: You are quite welcome! Happy to help. :) If my response solves your issue, please consider marking it as the answer to your question. Thank you!

Comment: Nice @RonSmith +1 for you.

Comment: But we have many different commodities like OS, Memory,RAM etc so including multiple replaces is complicated. Any suggestion ?

Comment: It appears that there are multiple spaces before each item. If this is the case and there are no other multi-spaces occurring within each item, you could replace a double space with a `vbcrlf` like so: `replace(Fields!Item2.Value,"  ",vbcrlf)`.